# Python on Git Bash

Tags: git, python-2.7

I'm new to Git Bash and have to use it for a project I am collaborating on. Currently I was trying out some standard python code that I have used in other programs to make sure that my Git Bash was working correctly. I keep on getting errors whenever I try to use libraries like numpy and pylab (pretty standard). I was wondering if there was a way to get my libraries from my canopy environment onto my Git Bash environment so that I can consolidate how much I have to move my files around.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the `python` executable from your environment?

Comment: Yes I started of doing the basic "hello world" and simple math. That was working fine, it was only when I tried to use commands from other libraries that I ran into this issue. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Pretty much. I haven't tried canopy, so I can't more.

Comment: No worries thank you for replying though